# Can't save Image to database using CarrierWave Direct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using CarrierWave Direct with Sidekiq to upload images to Amazon S3 in the background. The images are being uploaded as expected, but I can't seem to add the image record to the database. When I raise errors, I get that `filename can't be blank`.

Here is the relevant code:

**app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb**

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader

  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type

end
```

**app/controllers/admin/images_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @uploader = Image.new.filename
    @uploader.success_action_redirect = new_admin_project_image_url(@project)
    render "new"
  end

  def new
    @image = Image.new
    @image.filename = params[:key]
    @image.imageable = @project
    unless @image.save
      raise @image.errors.to_yaml
    end
  end
```

**app/models/image.rb**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :imageable_id, :imageable_type, :filename

  validates :filename, presence: true
  validates :imageable_id, presence: true
  validates :imageable_type, presence: true

  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

  mount_uploader :filename, ImageUploader
end
```

**app/views/admin/images/new.html.erb**

```
<%= direct_upload_form_for @uploader do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.file_field :filename %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Upload Image" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a similar question that was returning a different error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25710418/2241124).

The solution in both cases was the same. `carrierwave_direct` uses "filename" as a method. Therefore, naming the column in the database `filename` is very what is causing the issue here.